# Get data from SQFLite without widget in Flutter & Data

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sqflite

I'm writing a project with flutter. I used bloc pattern and SQFLite in my project.

I want to get data from SQFLite but I don't want to use the widget structure. I just want to return an integer value. The function I use is as follows. Can you help me about how I should change the function?

```
 getEmployeeWidget() {
        return StreamBuilder(
      stream: employeeBloc.employee,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<EmployeeModel>> snapshot) {

        return getEmployeeDatas(snapshot, context);
      },
    );
  }
```

```
  getEmployeeDatas(AsyncSnapshot<List<EmployeeModel>> snapshot, BuildContext context) 
 {
    int age;
    employeeBloc.getEmployes(query: employeId);
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      EmployeeModel employeeModel = snapshot.data[0];

      age = employeeModel.age;
      return snapshot.data.length != 0 ? age : 0;
    } else{

      return 0;
    }
  }
```